# Bug with bootstrap nav toggle on Wordpress and responsive css

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I use my theme in localhost and there is a bug with nav toggle and responsive css (I believe).
Here is the html code for my menu:

```
<nav class="main-menu">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <!-- Toggle Button -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse clearfix">
        <ul class="navigation clearfix">
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="project.html">Project</a></li>
            <li><a href="partners.html">Partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="people.html">People</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And here is what i use in wordpress :

```
<nav class="main-menu">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <!-- Toggle Button -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse clearfix">

    <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location'    => 'menu-1',

            'menu_class'        => 'navigation clearfix',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
                );
    ?>

    </div>
</nav>
```

But that doesn’t work.

So, I put the following into the functions.php:

```
require_once get_template_directory() . '/wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
    register_nav_menus( array(
    'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'visionitn' ),
));
```

And all css files in a function:

```
function add_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'revolution-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/revolution-slider.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'slider-setting', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/slider-setting.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/responsive.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/font-awesome.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'flaticon', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/flaticon.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/animate.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/owl.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery.fancybox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/jquery.fancybox.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
```

The problem is that toggle button does not work compared to my static html template when you reduce the screen to mobile resolution.

And the font size of my web page is little bigger than in my static template.
I also have some responsive css that doesn’t work.

Comment: It would also help if you included the html output of your menu (like what you'd see in your browser's developer tools) to help debug. I have a hunch it's an issue with the menu generation with Wordpress (an extra div perhaps?).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, here is the html output i have:

'

```
<!--Nav Outer-->
                        <div class="nav-outer clearfix">
                            <!-- Main Menu -->
                            <nav class="main-menu">
                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                    <!-- Toggle Button -->
                                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse clearfix">

                                <div class="menu-menu-principal-container"><ul id="menu-menu-principal" class="navigation clearfix"><li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-7 current_page_item menu-item-9 active"><a title="Home" href="http://localhost/vision-itn/">Home</a></li>
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22"><a title="Project" href="http://localhost/vision-itn/project/">Project</a></li>
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a title="Partners" href="http://localhost/vision-itn/partners/">Partners</a></li>
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20"><a title="People" href="http://localhost/vision-itn/people/">People</a></li>
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-19"><a title="News" href="http://localhost/vision-itn/news/">News</a></li>
</ul></div>                                
                                </div>
                            </nav>
                            <!-- Main Menu End-->

                            <!--Btn Outer-->
                            <div class="btn-outer">
                                <a href="contact.html" class="theme-btn quote-btn btn-style-one">GET In Touch</a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <!--Nav Outer End-->
```

'